# Derivative Product rule for non-commutative objects?

Tags: derivatives

lets say I have objects $f$ and $g$, for which one can define a derivative with the typical properties.

The product rule would be expected to be

$$
d(fg)=(df)g+f\,dg
$$

But what if $f$ and $g$ are not commutative?

$$
[f,g]\neq 0\implies d(fg)=\text{?}
$$

Does the product rule get modified?

Comment: You would have to define derivative in this space you are using

Comment: The rule you provided is generally correct even when $f$ and $g$ are not commutative. It would be wrong to say $d(fg) = f d(g) + g d(f)$, for example, because $g$ and $d(f)$ may not commute. To properly answer this question, I'd have to know what you mean by "typical properties" since usually, the product rule is such a typical property.

Comment: @MarkSaving : Could I suggest writing $d(fg) = f\,dg + g\,df,$ with a thin space between $f$ and $dg$ and between $g$ and $df,$ just as one writes $f(x)\,dx$ rather than $f(x)dx$?

Comment: In at least some non-commutative contexts (e.g. matrices of functions of a single variable), we have things like $d(fg)=(\mathrm df)g+f\,\mathrm dg$ (where the order of multiplication in things like $f\,\mathrm dg$ matters). I would argue that this product rule is one of the "typical properties" (in fact, it's basically the definition of a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_%28differential_algebra%29). Did you have a particular context in mind?

Comment: @MarkS. Yes when one creates a gauge covariant derivative, such as the ones used in physics. $D_\mu=\partial_\mu + iq A_\mu$. So I am thinking $D_\mu(fg)=?$, if $[f,g]\neq 0$.

Comment: That context would help refine your question greatly. Instead of "what happens with non-commutative stuff", it could be more like "what is the product rule for the noncommutative situation of a gauge covariant derivative?"